# Configurable Mongo database url and name in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to configure mongodb properties through `application-{environment-name}.properties` for connecting to mongodb.

Here's my code for making connection to mongo:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SpringMongoConfig {

    @Value("${db.connectionURL}")
    private String databaseURL;

    @Value("${db.name}")
    private String databaseName;

    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("database url: " + databaseURL + " db name: " + databaseName);
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(databaseURL), databaseName);
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
        return mongoTemplate;
    }
}
```

Here's my `application-test.properties` file:

```
db.connectionURL=localhost
db.name=rahab
```

I'm getting null values for `databaseURL` and `databaseName`. My idea is that the values are still not available during bean creation. But I don't have any idea to achieve this.

Comment: Did you activate the `test` profile? Try specifying `spring.profiles=test` in `application.properties` to see if it still doesn't work

Comment: @OriDar Tried doing that. In the terminal, I see the database url and name getting printed twice. One with the actual values followed by null values after which I get this message on terminal: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Database name must not be empty!`

Comment: You should also activate the profile by adding `@Profile("test")` to `SpringMongoConfig`. Note however that the specified mongo configuration will be only available for test profile. You should read sections 24 (configuration) 25 (profiles) and the mongodb section of Spring boot reference documentation for better understanding

Comment: I don't know what you have got the message twice printed. I suspect that you have duplicate configuration classes where one is properly set in conjunction to profile, and one doesn't

Answer (score 0):

you can use PropertySource in the configuration to specify the location of the properties file which you have created. The example code is given below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource("application-test.properties")
public class SpringMongoConfig {

@Value("${db.connectionURL}")
private String databaseURL;

@Value("${db.name}")
private String databaseName;

@Bean
public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("database url: " + databaseURL + " db name: " + databaseName);
    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(databaseURL), databaseName);
}

@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    return mongoTemplate;
}
}
```

Hope it helps to solve your issue.